# Совпадение даты со значением в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Есть скрипт календаря, простейший. Выводит текущий месяц в виде сетки.
Не получается сформулировать запрос к определенной таблице БД, чтобы если дата присутствует в БД, она закрашивалась цветом в календаре.
Интересует и привязка к пользователю. Для этого в той же базе есть поле uid.

**UPDATE**
Код прилагаю:

```
/* Функция генерации календаря */
function draw_calendar($month,$year){
  /* Начало таблицы */
  $calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';
  /* Заглавия в таблице */
  $headings = array('ПН','ВТ','СР','ЧТ','ПТ','СБ','ВС');
  $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';
  /* необходимые переменные дней и недель... */
  $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
  $running_day = $running_day - 1;
  $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
  $days_in_this_week = 1;
  $day_counter = 0;
  $dates_array = array();
  /* первая строка календаря */
  $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
  /* вывод пустых ячеек в сетке календаря */
  for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
    $days_in_this_week++;
  endfor;
  /* дошли до чисел, будем их писать в первую строку */
  for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
      /* Пишем номер в ячейку */
      $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';
      /** ЗДЕСЬ МОЖНО СДЕЛАТЬ MySQL ЗАПРОС К БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ! ЕСЛИ НАЙДЕНО СОВПАДЕНИЕ ДАТЫ СОБЫТИЯ С ТЕКУЩЕЙ - ВЫВОДИМ! **/
$query = mysql_query("select * from table where uid = 17");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
echo $result['date'];
}
      /** ЗДЕСЬ МОЖНО СДЕЛАТЬ MySQL ЗАПРОС К БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ! ЕСЛИ НАЙДЕНО СОВПАДЕНИЕ ДАТЫ СОБЫТИЯ С ТЕКУЩЕЙ - ВЫВОДИМ! **/
      $calendar.= str_repeat('<p> </p>',2);

    $calendar.= '</td>';
    if($running_day == 6):
      $calendar.= '</tr>';
      if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
        $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
      endif;
      $running_day = -1;
      $days_in_this_week = 0;
    endif;
    $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
  endfor;
  /* Выводим пустые ячейки в конце последней недели */
  if($days_in_this_week < 8):
    for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
      $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
    endfor;
  endif;
  /* Закрываем последнюю строку */
  $calendar.= '</tr>';
  /* Закрываем таблицу */
  $calendar.= '</table>';

  /* Все сделано, возвращаем результат */
  return $calendar;
}
```

В середине кода я выполняю запрос к БД, в котором вытаскиваю все записи текущего пользователя. 
Так вот вопросов несколько:
1. Почему он в результате echo выводит список полученных дат столько раз, сколько дней в месяце? То есть результаты он выводит все в каждой ячейке календаря.
2. Как мне сравнить дату из $result['date']; с датами текущего месяца.
3. и соответственно, если дата совпала, прописать какой-либо стиль этой ячейке.

P.S. Даты в БД в формате yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

БД не сможет закрасить цветом ячейку, она только хранит и обрабатывает данные. Вытягивай данные за последний месяц, а затем разбирай их и выставляй свойства нужным ячейкам.

Comment: вот какбы и хотел попросить помощи. Данные я например вытащу так:
SELECT date FROM table WHERE uid='{$uid}'
Выведет все даты нужного пользователя, а дальше затык))

Answer (score 1):

Ну так сделайте результат выборки дат массивом

Пример кода (*В случае если записывать даты в БД в формате **datetime***):

```
$sql_query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%c') as day
              FROM table WHERE uid=" . $uid . " AND MONTH(datetime)=" . $month;
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql_query);
while ($sql_row = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result)){
    $array[] = $sql_row['day'];
}
```

Если же даты записываются в **varchar**, как *yyyy-mm-dd*, можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями или банальным **substring**, для этого изменим запрос sql

```
$sql_query = "SELECT SUBSTRING(date, 9, 2) as day
FROM table WHERE uid=" . $uid . " AND SUBSTRING(date, 6, 2) = " . $month;
```

В итоге в массиве *$array[]* будет список дат указанного пользователя за указанный месяц.
Выполнять этот запрос до вызова вашей ф-ции.

Нам осталось проверить является ли дата генерируемая вашим скриптом элементом массива:

```
/* Пишем номер в ячейку */
if (in_array($list_day, $array))
    $calendar.= '<div class="day-number mark">'.$list_day.'</div>';
else
    $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';
```

Не забудьте передать массив в ф-цию

```
function draw_calendar($month, $year, $array = null)
```

Comment: Можно кусочек кода, примерный?