# Присвоить класс элементу, если значение есть в БД

Tags: ajax, php, база-данных, javascript

Здравствуйте.

http://jsfiddle.net/N2EGr/7/
Подскажите, как присвоить класс элементу (ячейке таблицы), если ее значение есть в БД?
Вся трудность в том, что в ячейках у меня только дни, а в бд дата полностью в формате yyyy-mm-dd. Нужно, чтобы при загрузке страницы проверялись, есть ли такие дни в БД, и им присваивался класс .click - они будут краситься в красный.

**UPD.**
На данный момент ситуация такая. 
Если я перед вызовом функции прописываю `var json_data = <? echo $json_data;?>;` то через alert выводится значения через запятую. Это не хитрость?)) Вот такая конструкция работает как положено (с учетом изменений из Вашего комментария про inarray) `var json_data = [11,15,19];`
А такая не работает: `var json_data = <? echo $json_data;?>;`
Хотя `alert(json_data);` дает одинаковый ответ.

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум, при инициализации календаря отправить все тот же POST ajax`ом с данными (year, month, uid) очередному обработчику, который, отталкиваясь от этих данных, вернет массив дат.

А в генераторе календаря уже проверять, есть ли на данный момент генерируемое число в этом массиве.
____
Я, кстати, не сильно изучал правила данного форума, но мне так кажется, не очень правильно, что у вас так много заданных вопросов по (практически) одному вопросу…

Comment: Прочитайте про `mysql_fetch_row` и `mysql_fetch_assoc`, тогда поймете, почему `$array[] = $sql_row['day']` пустой.

Запрос к БД, вы должны отталкиваться от года/месяца а не вытягивать их
    `$sql_query = "SELECT SUBSTRING(vihodnoy, 9, 2) as day
                 FROM t_table
                 WHERE
                    user_id=6 AND
                    SUBSTRING(vihodnoy, 6, 2) = {$_POST(mont)} AND
                    SUBSTRING(vihodnoy, 1, 4) = {$_POST(year)}";`

После цикла:
    `$json_data = json_encode($array);
    echo $json_data;`

А что касается скрипта календаря - покажите код хотя бы..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/js3pxwnL/11/
Я уже что-то совсем запутался. Прямо кажется, что где-то вокруг да около хожу, но почему-то не работает.
А насчет пустого массива, спасибо, разобрался. Получаю массив в виде ["11","15","18"]. Если беру и задаю в скрипте переменную вручную с такими значениями, то отмечается лишь первое число. Но нужно чтобы передавалось скриптом все, а у меня переменная не определена пишет.

Comment: Что касается только первого числа, замените условие на `if ($.inArray(d.getDate(), date_json ) !== -1)`, связанно с тем, что `inArray` возвращает позицию вхождения либо `-1` в случае отсутствия.

А насчет путого `date_json`, оказывается, обрабатывать ответ сервера можно только в теле функции `success`, не вынося эти данные за пределы, поэтому нужно как-то его перехитрить.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: http://rep-trade.ru, все, что успел, почему-то перестал срабатывать `$.inArray`, тип `date_json`, что ли, возвращается как `str`?..

В `javascript` нет `echo`, вот оно у вас и не работает, код обработчика `dates.php` http://ideone.com/ibBg7X

Будет время - доработаю.  
Да и негде уже общаться в пределах этой темы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update (13.10.2014)

- [Живой пример](http://rep-trade.ru)
- [Код скрипта](http://jsfiddle.net/6qkgzszq/)
- [Код обработчика](http://ideone.com/7FSY9r)

---

Ну, вот если бы вы хоть указали, что из выше мной написанного вам не понятно, получается все?

Как средствами Ajax отправить данные, помните? (Откройте ваш фидл). Добавьте такой же запрос в начале функции генерации календаря переменные year, month у вас есть (их принимает функция), uid сами подумайте, откуда взять.

Запрос отправлен, теперь обработчик ищет даты, соответствующие этим трем критериям (год, месяц, пользователь). Пример запроса смотрите в моем ответе [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/366220/php-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4). Результат выборки нам необходимо передать обратно в скрипт генерации календаря, для этого просто выведем массив (используя echo, или print, или даже  print_f) в удобном для JavaScript формате. Почитайте в Интернете, как передавать переменные/массивы/данные из php в JavaScript, json как подсказка.

Ну что, теперь у функции create calendar появились еще данные. Достаточно обработать их (надеюсь, вы уже нашли, как) и воспользоваться функцией inarray для сравнения, примерно так:

Заменили

```
table += '<td>'+d.getDate()+'</td>';
```

на

```
if (
$.inArray( d.getDate(), your_array )) {table += '<td class="click">'+d.getDate()'</td>';}

Else {table += '<td>'+d.getDate()+'</td>';}
```

Повторения кода можно (нужно) исключить, но так, я думаю, будет нагляднее.

```
--------------------------
    UPDATE:
--------------------------
```

Изначально хотел бы обратить внимание на то что я ошибся в синтаксисе функции `SUBSTRING`, третий параметр в ней - это длина извлекаемой строки а не позиция последнего символа (как я изначально понял), соответственно запрос выбора отдельных сегментов нужно поправить, как это делается я показал в [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be1102/2)

Касаемо вашего обработчика: теги  в нем не нужны, просто выводите `echo $json;`
Я не понял почему вы выбираете только по месяцу, а год упускаете, впрочем, возможно ваши задачи это позволяют.

Исходя из моей ошибки касаемо `SUBSTRING`, запрос в обработчике должен выглядеть как то так:  `$sql_query = "SELECT SUBSTRING(vihodnoy, 9, 2) as day FROM table WHERE user_id={$uid} AND SUBSTRING(vihodnoy, 6, 2) = {$month} AND SUBSTRING(date, 1, 4) = {$year}";`

Насчет `inArray`, а где определяется `date_json` у вас? Ну проверку вижу, а вот задание значений для него?
Нужно же было обработать ответ обработчика:

```
var date_json;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: your_url,
    data: "month="+month + "&year="+year,
    success: function(data) {
        date_json = JSON.parse(data);
    }
});
```

Обратите внимание на функцию `success`, в ее теле мы получаем и преобразуем json-строку в массив.

Старайтесь более вникать в решения в коде, у вас образуется большая каша, и очень много ошибок именно потому что вы не глядя вставляете куски чужого кода. К тому же куски кода (не важно мои или других участников) не проверяются в реальных условиях, максимум на локальных машинах или же на спец.сервисах, но отнюдь не в вашем проекте, поэтому работоспособность оного необходимо проверять и подстраивать под свои нужды в любом случае!

Comment: Это же ваш проект, чего вы разрешения у сторонних спрашиваете? :-)

Насколько я помню, у вас было желание менять месяц/год в календаре, как вы узнаете обработчиком, какой именно месяц отмечает пользователь? К тому же данные идут одним запросом…
___
Ваша проблема была в: 1) отсутствовали переменные your_url, your_uid; 2) отправка запроса должна была присутствовать в самом теле функции; 3) данные, передаваемые обработчику, не верные.

http://jsfiddle.net/js3pxwnL/1/

Никогда не отключайте консоль разработчика (Ctrl+Shift+I для Chrome-подобных браузеров).

Comment: Добавил рабочий пример к ответу, разгребайтесь ;)